# Transferring information from one form to another, to be displayed in an email

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I am trying to get the data from a richtextbox from one form to the original form to be sent in a email. I can't use the typical method because i'm not putting the value into another richtextbox. This is an example of what you normally do

```
            CVariable cvariable = new CVariable(rchtxtbox.text);
        cvariable.ShowDialog();
```

I have 6 different forms getting information for the 6 different locations. Itwould be a pain to out 6 richtextboxes on my form. So i am trying to by pass that and store them in the value below. That way I have the system setup so a user can select which location an email is suppose to go to based off checkboxes. Based off the corresponding selection an email is generated and sent to locations. Here's what I can't figure out, how do I get the info in a richtextbox from a separate form into that variable which is declared to be used in the email.

```
string Icomments = "goes here";
```

That is the value it needs to be in. The main form is what the data needs to relay back to. Does anyone have an suggestions? If you need more code or clarification let me know.

Comment: Don't understand what you said at all. Try rephrasing it. Don't bring your actual context into question, you should try to figure out what actually you need and even just post example code to demonstrate it. That's how you should follow to ask some easy-to-read and easy-to-understand question.

Comment: @KingKing see if that is better

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to retrieve the text inside a RichTextBox inside a Form?
Use the .Rtf property of the RichTextBox.
For example,

```
string mycomments = Form1.RichTextBox1.Rtf;
```

Where **Form1** is the name of your form, and **RichTextBox1** is the name of the box.

If you just the want the plain text, use Text instead of Rtf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm getting your question correctly but I think you could create a public get method on the form that has the rich text boxes and call that public get method from the email form.